# Python - Plot Multiple Dataframes by Month and Day (Ignore Year)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have multiple dataframes having different years data.

The data in dataframes are:

```
>>> its[0].head(5)
            Crocs
date             
2017-01-01     46
2017-01-08     45
2017-01-15     43
2017-01-22     43
2017-01-29     41

>>> its[1].head(5)
            Crocs
date             
2018-01-07     23
2018-01-14     21
2018-01-21     23
2018-01-28     21
2018-02-04     25

>>> its[2].head(5)
            Crocs
date             
2019-01-06     90
2019-01-13     79
2019-01-20     82
2019-01-27     82
2019-02-03     81
```

I tried to plot all these dataframes in single figure (graph), yeah i accomplished but it was not what i wanted.

I plotted the dataframes using the following code

```
>>> for p in its:
    plt.plot(p.index,p.values)
>>> plt.show()
```

and i got the following graph
[image: Graph i Got by Combing all dfs]

but this is not what i wanted
i want the graph to be like this
[image: Graph i want]

**Simply** i want graph to ignore years and plot by month and days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try of converting the datetime index to timeseries integers based on month and date and plot

```
df3 = pd.concat(its,axis=1)
xindex= df3.index.month*30 + df3.index.day
plt.plot(xindex,df3)
plt.show()
```

If you want to have datetime information than integers you can add xticks to frame

```
labels = (df3.index.month*30).astype(str)+"-" + df3.index.day.astype(str)
plt.xticks(df3.index.month*30 + df3.index.day, labels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just one more question
how can i fix this thing by setting interval betweens the labels of date and time

Comment: glad to help @IjazUrRahim, we can try of using pd.to_timedelta to fix the specific time intervals without considering year, check pd.to_timedelta and fix it as index. i will update the code inbetween :-)

Comment: @Nagakiran: the label does not properly show. Could you please help with that?